# Android touch input problem

Tags: java, android, input, touch

In my little game, I have a background and a player, and obstacles to prevent the player from gaining points. So the player needs to move to avid these obstacles, right? Well my method of taking touch input works and when the user touches the right/left side of the screen to move in the corresponding direction. For some reason my method requires the user to tap the screen once for every single movement (4 pixels) of the player. I want the user to be able to hold their finger down on the direction they wish to go, and not have to continually tap that side of the screen a few hundred times. I'm pretty new to android, so I don't really know how to implement this. I have tried a game loop (it just crashed my game), and I've tried a separate thread to try and repeat the action, but it never gets executed even after I call "game.run()" and with "game.start()" it crashes. Can anyone show me a simple way to make it to where me player will keep moving when holding your finger on the side you wish to move towards? I imagine it's simple and I'm over complicating it, but I am a little clueless. Please provide an example, and not just a "Do it like that" etc. Because again, I am a little clueless in this department. Code pastebin'd below.

My code: http://pastebin.com/3EetUHCx

Answer (score 0):

You want to **create** a new `Runnable` object in which to put the code, not to **implement** Runnable in the main class. That way you will separate the event handling from the main UI.

Even a better option would be to extend [**SurfaceView**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) instead of View in your Draw class and create a Tread object inside that SurfaceView to handle the actual drawing.

Take a look at the [**Lunar Lander example**](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/LunarLander/index.html) from the android dev guide.